# Pcf appdynamics spring actuator

Tags: appdynamics

We have a spring boot app running in pivotal cloud foundry and we have also configured appdynamics and we can now see our app on appd controller GUI. I would like to build a appd dashboard and call actuator end points like info , health. How do i do this? Or I am also open to other ideas on building appd dashboard for micro services
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

AppDynamics itself powerful enough to provide all sort of information, However if you still want actuator data to be captured and displayed then you may need to use AppD extension. Please refer below official link to AppDyanmics Exchange.

https://www.appdynamics.com/community/exchange/

if the relevant is not available you may need write your own.